# Trigger an event only in the current div

Tags: jquery

I have multiple boxes with a "info" button in each that toggle a modal with a description but when i click on one button it triggers all the modals in the same time instead of showing only the one inside the current box. Anyone can help me figure it out?

here is my code:

```js
$('.info-btn').click(function () {
  $('.modal').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.box{ color:#341f12; background-color: #EFEFEF;  padding:20px;  margin:20px }
.modal{opacity:0}
.open{opacity:1 !important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
Josh...
<button class="info-btn">More info</button>
<div class="modal">modal 1</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
Luca...
<button class="info-btn">More info</button>
<div class="modal">modal 2</div>
</div>


<div class="box">
Kevin...
<button class="info-btn">More info</button>
<div class="modal">modal 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to .next()

Alternative in case you want to move the modal:

`$(this).closest('.box').find('.modal').toggleClass('open');`

```js
$('.info-btn').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('.modal').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #341f12;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px
}

.modal {
  opacity: 0
}

.open {
  opacity: 1 !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  Josh...
  <button class="info-btn">More info</button>
  <div class="modal">modal 1</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  Luca...
  <button class="info-btn">More info</button>
  <div class="modal">modal 2</div>
</div>


<div class="box">
  Kevin...
  <button class="info-btn">More info</button>
  <div class="modal">modal 3</div>
</div>
```

Without jQuery

```js
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains('info-btn')) {
    tgt.closest('.box').querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #341f12;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px
}

.modal {
  opacity: 0
}

.open {
  opacity: 1 !important
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    Josh...
    <button class="info-btn">More info</button>
    <div class="modal">modal 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    Luca...
    <button class="info-btn">More info</button>
    <div class="modal">modal 2</div>
  </div>


  <div class="box">
    Kevin...
    <button class="info-btn">More info</button>
    <div class="modal">modal 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work perfectly thanks! i don't know why i was looking for something more complexe :D

Comment: @Nitheesh read the second line of the answer `Alternative in case you want to move the modal: $(this).closest('.box').find('.modal').toggleClass('open');`

Comment: Identical in functionality to your `$(this).closest('.box').children('.modal').toggleClass('open');`

Answer (score 0):

Select the `nextElementSibling` of current target using `e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling` and toggle class using

```
$(e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling).toggleClass('open');
```

But this will work only if the `.modal` comes just next to button (I have put this commented in the solution)

OR

Select parent and find children with class `modal` with jQuery selector for the same will be

```
$(this).parent().children('.modal').toggleClass('open');
```

This will select the element with class `modal` under the same parent div.

```js
$('.info-btn').click(function (e) {
  // $(e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling).toggleClass('open');
  $(this).parent().children('.modal').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #341f12;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px
}

.modal {
  opacity: 0
}

.open {
  opacity: 1 !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  Josh...
  <button class="info-btn">More info</button>
  <div class="modal">modal 1</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  Luca...
  <button class="info-btn">More info</button>
  <div class="modal">modal 2</div>
</div>


<div class="box">
  Kevin...
  <button class="info-btn">More info</button>
  <div class="modal">modal 3</div>
</div>
```

**Generic Solution.**

- Find the closest element with the class name of parent.
- Find the child element with targeted class name.
- Toggle its visibility

Working fiddle:

```js
$('.info-btn').click(function (e) {
  $(this).closest('.box').children('.modal').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #341f12;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px
}

.modal, .modal1 {
  opacity: 0
}

.open {
  opacity: 1 !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  Im a simple div
  <button class="info-btn">More info</button>
  <div class="modal">modal 3</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  Im contained inside another parent
  <button class="info-btn">More info</button>
  <div class="modal">modal 3</div>
</div>


<div class="box">
  I have a dive between `.modal` and `info-btn`
  <button class="info-btn">More info</button>
  <div class="modal1">modal 3</div>
  <div class="modal">modal 3</div>
</div>
```